# C# Combobox behaviour in Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a Datagridview with a column that has a combobox as editing control. Say I choose value X in the combobox in the first row. When I open the combobox in row 2 it will select value X as default (when the combobox was empty before edit), even if value X isn't the first item in the list of the combobox. Why doesn't it select the first item (if it wants to select an item anyway)?

I don't know if it is relevant, but the grid and the combo are bound to Linq2sql objects.

Comment: If you select value "Y" in row 2, then drop down the box in row 1: is "Y" selected? What I mean is: are you using only one datasource for the combobox?

Comment: @stephan-keller No what I mean is: I start editing row 1 and select Y as value in the combo. Then I add a new row (row 2) in which the combo at first is emmpty, but when I want to change the value it will jump to value Y. I can change it to another value, without effecting row 1, but I think it's kinda weird.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't specify any defaults anywhere?

Comment: True. Because a value is not required for this field, I don't want to set a default value.

Comment: Did you try setting up the "selecteditem" property of the combobox to "" or to null in the beginning of the edit row event?